# xsd extension base element with attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Suppose i have got schema

```
 <xs:complexType name="superType">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="s:itemType" name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>

        <xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>

    </xs:complexType>
```

and my next element:

```
<xs:complexType name="elegantType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>

            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

As you can see **elegantType** and **superType** have got the same attribute :

```
<xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>
```

Its possible to create base type for that element using extension?

I try define base type but i have got error : 
 **The content type of a derived type and that of its base must both be mixed or both be element-only. Type 'superType' is element only, but its base type is not.**

This is what i try to do :

```
            <xs:element type="s:itemType" name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>


   <!-- <xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>-->

</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="resourceBase" mixed="true">

    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>

        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>

</xs:complexType>
```

My problem is that i have got many element and most of them have got the same attribute. And i need create base element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have many elements with repeating attributes, you can use declare them in attribute groups and reuse the attributeGroup object in several elements:

In your schema you can declare a group like this:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="attributes">
    <xs:attribute type="s:stringNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="s:extraType" name="extra" use="optional" default="ALL"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

And then just add it in the place where you would add your attributes:

```
<xs:complexType name="superType">
    <xs:sequence>...</xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="attributes"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="elegantType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="attributes"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Ok. But when i am using xjc i have got :`@XmlElements({
@XmlElement(name = "type1", type = Type1.class),
@XmlElement(name = "type2", type = Type2.class),
@XmlElement(name = "type3", type = Type3.class)
})
protected List<Object> type1OrType2OrType3;`
But i want to have got:

`List<Type1> type1;
List<Type2> type2:
List<Type3> type3
`
or 
`List<T extends BaseType> types`

Comment: Hmmm. You probably will have to map that using a JAXB bindings file. Since that's JAXB-related, it would be better if you asked a new question describing your problem, and be sure to tag it with JAXB so you can get help from a JAXB specialist.